# Appending string data to an existing REG_MULTI_SZ Windows registry entry

Tags: batch-file, cmd, append, registry

`REG ADD` changes the entire entry. I have not been able to make `REG ADD ~` work.

Windows registry contains multiple string zero values. This is what `REG_MULTI_SZ` means. How can a new string be appended? `REG ADD` deletes all string previously in the entry and writes only the new one there although `REG_MULTI_SZ` is specified in the `REG ADD` command.

Some say `~` before the string means append instead of overwrite. However, I do not what the exact syntax is. How can I use `~`?

**[Edit]**
Here is the simplified version of the question :

I have a registry entry `KEYROOT\KEY\ENTRY` which is type **`REG_MULTI_SZ`**. In this entry, there are string zeroes `abcd\0` and `efgh\0`. How can I add `ijkl\0` in order to have all three: abcd, efgh and ijkl in the registry entry `\ENTRY` and not only `ijkl`?

I want to do this only with Batch Script or Command Prompt commands.

Please, note : I have tried many things with `REG` and am unable to find a solution and I am not sure whether there is such.

I will be very thankful for any suggestions but I would like to ask you all to concentrate on the `~` possibility. Microsoft says when there is `~` before the string, the string is considered to be appended to the other strings and not to overwrite them.

I have tried many variations but am unable to get the correct syntax of `~`. Please, do provide information on how to use `~` before the string to be appended.

I found a solution. However, although the solution works, to add a string to the registry entry is not a good idea because Microsoft allows strings to be appended with hex data. Anyway, here is what I have been able to do :

1. Read the value of the registry in a batch string variable :

**`FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,* skip=2" %%G IN ('REG QUERY "Root\Key" /v Entry') DO SET EntryContents=%%H`**

Note the reverse apostrophes `.

Now, the entry of the registry key is in the variable `EntryContents`.

2. Concatenate the new value to the old value

**`SET NewEntryContents=%EntryContents%%ContentsToBeAppended%`**

The variable `ContentsToBeAppended` has been set elsewhere in the batch file or may be a parameter. The variable `NewEntryContents` contains the concatenated strings of the old registry key entry contents and the string which is in the variable `ContentsToBeApended`.

3. Add `NewEntryContents` to the entry with REG ADD.

Again, when the entry value is read into a string variable, all hex contents would be ignored in case they are 00's or other values which may be out of the character range. A solution may be to somehow export the entry with REG to a file in hex format and then to somehow add only hex values to the file. The string characters must be converted to their hex values and appended to the file as well as any new hex values.

This answer provides the ability to read a registry entry which would be read in full with all characters such as \0 in a string variable. The string variable will get all characters. Example : In case the registry entry contains `PATH\NAME_OF_FILE\0PATH|NAME_OF_FILE`, all these will be read into the string variable. `\0` too. Just concatenate the new string, which may also contain`\0`'s, and reg add the overall string back to the registry.

The trick here is the for `/f` statement which skips 2 lines and takes the second string of the third line in G and the third ( the important one ) in H. All blanks and *'s, *.*'s, dits will be read too.

In order to add all blanks and *'s etcetera back to the entry with reg add, enclose the variable `NewEntryContents` in quotes :

**`REG ADD "Root\Key" /v Entry /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "%NewEntryContents%"`**

Hope this may help.

Also, the [~] sign works only when `REGEDIT` is used. `REGEDIT` is a better approach. Can save a key as is ( with hex ) in a file, then the file can be edited in the batch and then the newly edited key can be imported back to the registry. Pretty nasty, though. Also, I am not sure whether `REGEDIT` would export the strings and the hex data combined to the file.

Here are the checks for the availability of the entry and for an empty entry :

1. This checks whether the entry is there or not at all :

**`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" /v PendingFileRenameOperations`**

**`IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO THEREIS`**

2. After the for `/f` :

**`SET "EntryContents"="%EntryContents: =%" IF DEFINED EntryContents GOTO NOTEMPTY`**

The SET line is not necessary. Gets rid of blanks around the string. This is supposed to be done by the for `/f` anyway.

If defined checks the value. Best `EntryContents` never to have been defined before the for `/f`.

---

OK. I have managed to overcome all problems with batch script only.

Echo does echo all ASCII characters and can be made to output Unicode too, however, there are many more problems.

Anyway, I am unable to provide more information because of the amount of problems and solutions BUT, whoever is interested, can read the batch file I have made : http://www.steven-stanley-bayes.com/ForceDelete.zip

Comment: Read the value first using `reg query`, construct the new value, then `reg add`

Comment: I have tried this but to construct a new value proves to be very difficult. \C is read as Control for example. In case you know a way to get the old value, get the strings for ADD or export only the entry into a file, please, inform. Please, note I have not been able to export the entry only. The EXPORT and SAVE options of REG allow to export the whole key into a file but not the entry only. In case you know a way to store only the entry into a file, please, inform.

Comment: How about you provide the root, key, value and data that you are struggling with. I'm fairly certain that with a couple of carefully chosen character replacements any sensitive data would be protected, if that's why you're keeping it from us.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853911/reg-add-a-reg-multi-sz-multi-line-registry-value shows you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

*Lean and mean* batch-file alternative to the ~50KB script linked by OP:
~ Accepting a single parameter, either File or Folder
~ Confirmation prompt ([Cancel] to Clear previous entries)
~ Basic idiot proofing (don't process %Windir% for example)
~ Scripts will add an entry to right-click -- "SendTo" menu on first run

[Rename_On_Boot.bat](https://pastebin.com/2Z4R8tBJ)

```js
goto="Batch" /* Rename_On_Boot by AveYo v1
:RenOnBoot
set "input=%*" & call set "input=%%input:?=%%"                            &rem line below adds entry to right-click -- "SendTo" menu
if /i "_%~dp0"=="_%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\" (set .=) else copy /y "%~f0" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\" >nul 2>nul
if "_%1"=="_" color 4f & echo   ERROR! No input provided & ping -n 6 localhost >nul & exit /b
for %%# in ("C:\" "C:\Boot" "C:\Recovery" "%WINDIR%" "%WINDIR%\system32" "%ProgramData%" "%ProgramFiles%" "%USERPROFILE%") do (
 if /i "_%input%"=="_%%~#" color 4f & echo   ERROR! %%# is not safe to delete & ping -n 6 localhost >nul & exit /b
)
color 0B & echo   Please wait, folders might take a while .. & call cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" RenOnBoot "%input%" & exit /b
:RenOnBoot_Run_As_Admin
color 4f & echo   Asking permission to run as Admin.. & call cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" RunAsAdmin "%~f1???" & exit /b
:"Batch"
@echo off & setlocal disabledelayedexpansion & mode 96,4 & echo. & title %~nx0 by AveYo & if not exist "%~f1" goto :RenOnBoot
reg query HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Environment /v temp 1>nul 2>nul && goto :RenOnBoot || goto :RenOnBoot_Run_As_Admin
:"JScript" */
function RenOnBoot(f){
  var HKLM=0x80000002, k='SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager', v='PendingFileRenameOperations';
  var reg=GetObject('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/default:StdRegProv'), ws=WSH.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');  
  var confirmation=ws.Popup(" Rename on next boot? [OK]\n Clear previous entries? [Cancel]\n\n "+f,0,'Rename_On_Boot by AveYo',33);
  if (confirmation == 2) { reg.DeleteValue(HKLM, k, v); WSH.quit(); } // Clear existing entries on Cancel press and quit script
  var mtd=reg.Methods_('GetMultiStringValue').InParameters.SpawnInstance_(); mtd.hDefKey=HKLM; mtd.sSubKeyName=k; mtd.sValueName=v;
  var query=reg.ExecMethod_('GetMultiStringValue', mtd), regvalue=(!query.ReturnValue) ? query.SValue.toArray():[,], entries=[];
  var fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'), fn=fso.GetAbsolutePathName(f);
  entries.push('\\??\\'+fn,'\\??\\'+fn+'.ren');
  reg.CreateKey(HKLM, k); reg.SetMultiStringValue(HKLM, k, v, entries.concat(regvalue));
}
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=2 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='RenOnBoot') RenOnBoot(WSH.Arguments(1));

function RunAsAdmin(self, arguments) { WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application').ShellExecute(self, arguments, '', 'runas', 1) }
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=1 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='RunAsAdmin') RunAsAdmin(WSH.ScriptFullName, WSH.Arguments(1));
//
```

[Delete_On_Boot.bat](https://pastebin.com/ZBDCUDBg)

```js
goto="Batch" /* Delete_On_Boot by AveYo v1
:DelOnBoot
set "input=%*" & call set "input=%%input:?=%%"                            &rem line below adds entry to right-click -- "SendTo" menu
if /i "_%~dp0"=="_%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\" (set .=) else copy /y "%~f0" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\" >nul 2>nul
if "_%1"=="_" color 4f & echo   ERROR! No input provided & ping -n 6 localhost >nul & exit /b
for %%# in ("C:\" "C:\Boot" "C:\Recovery" "%WINDIR%" "%WINDIR%\system32" "%ProgramData%" "%ProgramFiles%" "%USERPROFILE%") do (
 if /i "_%input%"=="_%%~#" color 4f & echo   ERROR! %%# is not safe to delete & ping -n 6 localhost >nul & exit /b
)
color 0B & echo   Please wait, folders might take a while .. & call cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" DelOnBoot "%input%" & exit /b
:DelOnBoot_Run_As_Admin
color 4f & echo   Asking permission to run as Admin.. & call cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" RunAsAdmin "%~f1???" & exit /b
:"Batch"
@echo off & setlocal disabledelayedexpansion & mode 96,4 & echo. & title %~nx0 by AveYo & if not exist "%~f1" goto :DelOnBoot
reg query HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Environment /v temp 1>nul 2>nul && goto :DelOnBoot || goto :DelOnBoot_Run_As_Admin
:"JScript" */
function DelOnBoot(f){
  ListDir=function(src, _root,_list) {
    _root=_root || src, _list=_list || [];
    var root=fso.GetFolder(src), files=new Enumerator(root.Files), dirs=new Enumerator(root.SubFolders);
    while (!files.atEnd()) { _list.push(files.item()); files.moveNext(); }
    while (!dirs.atEnd()) { _list=ListDir(dirs.item().path, _root,_list); _list.push(dirs.item()); dirs.moveNext(); }
    return _list;
  };
  var HKLM=0x80000002, k='SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager', v='PendingFileRenameOperations';
  var reg=GetObject('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/default:StdRegProv'), ws=WSH.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');  
  var confirmation=ws.Popup(" Delete on next boot? [OK]\n Clear previous entries? [Cancel]\n\n "+f,0,'Delete_On_Boot by AveYo',33);
  if (confirmation == 2) { reg.DeleteValue(HKLM, k, v); WSH.quit(); } // Clear existing entries on Cancel press and quit script
  var mtd=reg.Methods_('GetMultiStringValue').InParameters.SpawnInstance_(); mtd.hDefKey=HKLM; mtd.sSubKeyName=k; mtd.sValueName=v;
  var query=reg.ExecMethod_('GetMultiStringValue', mtd), regvalue=(!query.ReturnValue) ? query.SValue.toArray():[,], entries=[];
  var fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'), fn=fso.GetAbsolutePathName(f);
  if (fso.FolderExists(fn)) { var list=ListDir(fn); for (var i in list) entries.push('\\??\\'+list[i],''); }
  entries.push('\\??\\'+fn,'');
  reg.CreateKey(HKLM, k); reg.SetMultiStringValue(HKLM, k, v, entries.concat(regvalue));
}
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=2 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='DelOnBoot') DelOnBoot(WSH.Arguments(1));

function RunAsAdmin(self, arguments) { WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application').ShellExecute(self, arguments, '', 'runas', 1) }
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=1 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='RunAsAdmin') RunAsAdmin(WSH.ScriptFullName, WSH.Arguments(1));
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not requested, you could probably use something like this in PowerShell:

```
$key = Get-Item "KEYROOT:\KEY\"
$values = $key.GetValue("ENTRY")
$values += "ijkl"
Set-ItemProperty "KEYROOT:\KEY\" "ENTRY" $values -Type MultiString
```

*Change KEYROOT, KEY & ENTRY to their genuine strings*

Comment: I am interested in a way to do this from a batch file or a command prompt but, thank you for your answer, I will look into PowerShell too.

Comment: You got the `REG [QUERY|ADD]` methods for doing that via @DavidPostill an hour ago. By now you should have incorporated code using his suggested method into your question by way of [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45673624/edit), if you were still having issues.

Comment: REG QUERY ADD will not work for various reasons or will be extremely difficult. Query cannot provide the data only but can provide the whole string with the key name, etcetera and a lot of \0 between the strings. The file has to be split and only the last portion be taken which is possible as here : http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429 but the tail section contains \0 and cannot be taken into one string. In case there was a way to delete the first portion of the file only and keep only the second portion, then this would be the data for the entry and some of the REG's may work

Comment: I have also posted a question to the Microsoft Community : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-winapps-tools/append-data-to-and-regmultisz-entry-of-a-registry/f28b743b-8249-4c2f-a38d-a112e310ae27

Answer (score 0):

The following batchfile does the job in four steps:

1. export the value into a file,
2. extract the value using the *for* command

in the subroutine

3. if the value is valid, concat the string and
4. finally write the value back.

In this code, HKCU\Software\AITEM is the registry key and AVALUE is the Name of the value. Finally "newstring" is the string you want to add to your list.

The echo command is just for debugging purposes an can be deleted.
The code only works if the key AITEM and the value AVALUE already exist and if AVALUE already has at least one string in its list.

```
@echo off
reg query HKCU\Software\AITEM /v AVALUE > tmp.txt
FOR /F "tokens=2,3*" %%a in (tmp.txt) do call :sub1 %%b
del tmp.txt


:sub1
if %1x==x goto end
echo %1
REG ADD HKCU\Software\AITEM /f /v AVALUE /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d %1\0newstring
:end
goto :eof
```

The following code also works if AVALUE does not exist or is empty:

```
@echo off
reg query HKCU\Software\AITEM /v AVALUE > tmp.txt
find "AVALUE" tmp.txt
if errorlevel 1 goto sub2

FOR /F "tokens=2,3*" %%a in (tmp.txt) do call :sub1 %%b
del tmp.txt


goto :eof

:sub2
REG ADD HKCU\Software\AITEM /f /v AVALUE /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d newstring
goto :eof

:sub1
REG ADD HKCU\Software\AITEM /f /v AVALUE /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d %1\0newstring
if errorlevel 1 REG ADD HKCU\Software\AITEM /f /v AVALUE /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d newstring
goto :eof
```

Comment: Very interesting. I have also looked into some DOS string commands to find a way to split the file after a given keyword, which in this case is REG_MULTI_SZ. Everything thereafter are the strings with \0 in between or nothing. Then, the trick would be to get them into a variable. I remember there may have been some way to split a file with TYPE and redirection but I do not fully recall.

Comment: You have completed an excellent solution. However, although two of your conditions are met : AVALUE and AITEM should be there, chances are AITEM would be empty very often. You have answered the closest possible, though. Maybe, I can check whether AITEM is empty and, when so, I can directly use REG ADD as there is nothing to overwrite. When not empty, your code does the job.

Comment: Here are a bunch of DOS string commands and tips whoever may be interested. I have not had a chance to look at them in depth yet : http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php

Comment: Remember : I do not know what data is in the entry. I either have to blindly append which should be possible but may not be or read part of the string given by QUERY and concatenate or append the desired string which I know to the unknown ones which have been in the registry entry. The entry may have been empty too.

Comment: You can add several tests to check whether the value exists or is empty. The command 'find "AVALUE" tmp.txt' and than check for %errorlevel%, which is 1 if the value did not exist. In that case just add your new string.

Comment: I added a second example. This also works if AVALUE does not exist or is empty.

Comment: I have done the checks and posted them in the new edit of the question as well as found the way online to solve the problems without a file. I am sure your examples are perfect and work perfectly and better. Thanks!

Comment: If you have found a better solution you should post it to help everyone reading this question in the future. If not, you should consider to accept this solution.