# INNO setup writing a multi line text constant to the registry

Tags: installation, inno-setup

During install I want to write a long multi line/paragraph chunk of text to a registry value

writing to a registry value is easy enough

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\my company\My software"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Message"; ValueData: "some text"

but I would rather define a multi line text constant to replace "some text"

i.e. something like

## mytext = "some long text value\r\ngoning onto another line"

Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\my company\My software"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Message"; ValueData: #mytext

I am probably being dull but I can't see how to do this - any help gratefully appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple variable should work.

```
#define mytext "some long text value\r\ngoing onto another line" 

[Registry] Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\my company\My software"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Message"; ValueData: "{#mytext}"
```

However, writing a `ValueType: string` to a registry in Windows means you are writing a `REG_SZ`. The `\r\n` will appear as text in the registry value. Most registry tools do not support carriage return in `REG_SZ` value. They will simply display the characters.

You will have to handle it yourself in the program that uses that registry value. Some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153879/how-do-i-add-a-multline-reg-sz-string-to-the-registry-from-the-command-line).

A better solution if it fits your requirements is to tell inno to use a `REG_MULTI_SZ` with the `ValueType: multisz`. [REG_MULTI_SZ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a sequence of null-terminated strings terminated by an empty string (\0). With inno `multisz`'s type value, you may use a special constant called `{break}` to embed line breaks. Consult the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) for the usage.

Comment: It's not that important what registry tools display, but what they, or better to mention - your application, can read (your application can process e.g. `<42>` as a line break if we are at :)